# how can i push json data to csharp list of object by javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, json

my question is pushing json list to C# list of object inside of javascript code. How can i push $scope.items into CustomColumns ?  requestData.CustomColumns.push($scope.items);  is not working... My C# model is :

```
  public partial class WorkflowDefinitionDTO {

    public List<WorkflowDefinitionCustomColumnDTO> CustomColumns { get; set; }

}

    public partial class WorkflowDefinitionCustomColumnDTO {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
    public decimal MinValue { get; set; }
    public decimal MaxValue { get; set; }
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public int Visibility { get; set; }
    public int Requirements { get; set; }
    public List<string> SelectTypeValues { get; set; }
}
```

My javascript code for pushing data:

```
                var requestData = {
            CustomColumns: []
                            };
        requestData.CustomColumns.push($scope.items);
```

$scope.items is below :

```
                $scope.items.push({
                Type: result.FieldType.value, Name: result.CustomFieldName, Format: "", MinValue: 0, MaxValue: 1000,
                DefaultValue: result.DefaultValue, Visibility: 1, Requirements: 0, CanBeChangebleOk: result.CanBeChangebleOk.value
            });
```

Comment: Do you want to send your data to an MVC controller?

Comment: yes. i want  to send your data to an MVC controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a basic example of how to pass arrays or lists to MVC controller. Here is jQuery code:

```
$.post('MyController/MyAction', { 'values': ['a', 'b', 'c']});
```

And the action looks like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(string[] values)
{
    ...
}
```

I see `$scope` variable. I have an impression that you use AngularJs. Thus you probably want to use `$http` service for Javascript web requests:

```
$http.post('MyController/MyAction', { 'values': ['a', 'b', 'c'] });
```

Hope it helps